# If H a subgroup, and the left and right cosets are equal, does this mean that H is the center?

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

> Theorem: If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $aH=Ha$ for every $a \in G$.

If H a subgroup, and the left and right cosets are equal, does this mean that H is the center? Isn't the definition of the center: the set of all a in G s.t. ax=xa for all x in G. But if the left and right cosets are equal isn't that the definition of center?

I know that the center of a group is normal, is every normal subgroup of a group the center of the group?

Comment: *is every normal subgroup of a group the center of the group* Do you mean "is every normal subgroup of a group **in** the center of the group"?

Comment: Got it. I'm not familiar with the proper wording yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: take the group of symmetries of an equilateral triangle, for example (or for that matter, the symmetries of a regular polygon with more sides.) The rotations form a normal subgroup which is clearly not in the center.

If you literally mean the question you asked:

> is every normal subgroup of a group the center of the group

then here is an easy way to see that's not true. For one thing, the entire group is always a normal subgroup of itself, and if it were the center, the group would have to be abelian.

Answer (score 3):

The equality $aH=Ha$ means that the sets
$$aH=\{ah:h\in H\}$$
and
$$Ha=\{ha:h\in H\}$$
are equal.

But if this is the case and if you pick some $h\in H$, you only know that $ah\in Ha$. That is, there exists some $h'$ in $H$ such that $ah=h'a$, and $h$ and $h'$ may be different.

Furthermore, if it is the case that
$$\forall h\in H(ah=ha)$$
that means that every element of $H$ commutes with every element of $G$. This means that $H$ is *included* in the center. **The** center of a group $G$ is unique, and it is the set of elements that commute with every element of $G$. (Exercise: can you show that this set is indeed a subgroup?)

Answer (score 1):

No, not every normal subgroup is equal to the center of the group. For example in an abelian group $A$ the center is always $A$ itself, but every subgroup of $A$ is normal.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. For example, $H = G$ is certainly a normal subgroup. If $G$ is not abelian, this is not a central subgroup.

Maybe the confusion comes from the "commutativity" kind of relation $aH = Ha$. This does NOT mean that $ah = ha$ for all $h \in H$. What this means is that for any $h \in H$, we can find a $h' \in H$ (not usually equal to $h$) such that $ah = h'a$.

Answer (score 1):

The center is defined based on elements while for a normal subgroup, it's based on cosets. So you might have $aH=Ha$ but within that, you could have $ah_1=h_2a$ where $h_1, h_2 \in H$ but they aren't equal.

i.e. What you can guarantee is simply that for any $h_1 \in H$, $\exists h_2 \in H$ s.t. $ah_1 = h_2 a$